# Konva load stage with images and background video

Tags: save, konvajs

Hey guys so I have this konva js app that has your typical background video just like the demo or close to it. I am able to play the video background and add image objects on top of it etc. Now I want a way to save the stage in its current state. So I do `state.stage.toJSON()` and as expected it creates a serialized JSON object. Now here's where I am hung up. when I load the stage like so   `state.stage = Konva.Node.create(data.stage, "container");` the stage data gets loaded (it is the correct size and so forth) yet there is no background video, no images or anything how do I fix this? I don't even know if `stage.toJSON` is correct but the point is I need to save it, leave the page and load it back up at a future date.

```
state.backgroundVideo = new Konva.Image({
  image: state.video,
  draggable: false
});
state.video.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", function(e) {
  state.backgroundVideo.width(state.width);
  state.backgroundVideo.height(state.height);
});

state.anim = new Konva.Animation(function() {
  // do nothing, animation just need to update the layer
}, state.layer);

state.layer.add(state.backgroundVideo);
state.layer.batchDraw();
const canvas = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0];
state.canvas = canvas;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks @lavrton your comments really helped me figure it out. Rather than loading the stage directly however I just saved the data from the stage used the data to rebuild the stage in the exact same way. Heres the code I used to get the data to save.

Heres my code:

```
const groups = state.stage.find("Group");
const stageData = [];
for (let x = 0; x < groups.length; x++) {
  let g = groups[x];
  let i = g.findOne("Image").getAttrs();
  let group = { x: g.getX(), y: g.getY() };
  let image = { x: i.width, y: i.height };
  let obj = { image, group, jsonId: g.getAttr("jsonId") };
  stageData.push(obj);
}
console.log("stageData", stageData);
```

Answer (score 1):

`node.toJSON()` doesnt serialize image or video objects from `Konva.Image` attributes.

To solve the issue you can save video or image src into custom attribute:

```js
image.setAttr('source', imageURL);
```

A simple string will be serialized into JSON. Then after you created a node from the JSON `Konva.Node.create(data.stage, "container");`

You need to find such nodes and restore image or video manually

```js
// "video-background" is a sample here
// you can define your own selector
const videoNode = stage.findOne('.video-background');
const source = videoNode.getAttr('source');

const video = document.createElement('video');
video.src = source;

videoNode.image(video);
```

For more information take a look here:

https://konvajs.org/docs/data_and_serialization/Complex_Load.html
https://konvajs.org/docs/data_and_serialization/Best_Practices.html

Comment: Okay but I am still confused. How do I add ids and classes that can actually be selected out of the stage and repopulated?

Comment: At the time when you create images or videos. Another way to set special attribute for image source like this: `image.setAttr('imageSource', imageURL)` and they find nodes with such attributes: `const allImages = stage.find(node => node.getAttr('imageSource'));`